# Async.Await not catching Task exception

Tags: exception, f#, task-parallel-library, f#-async

I have a Task that does not return anything. You can't do an Async.AwaitTask on such a Task, so you need to do an Async.AwaitIAsyncTask instead. Unfortunately this seems to just swallow any exceptions that the underlying Task throws out: -

```
TaskFactory().StartNew(Action(fun _ -> failwith "oops"))
|> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
|> Async.Ignore
|> Async.RunSynchronously

// val it : unit = ()
```

On the other hand, AwaitTask correctly cascades the exception: -

```
TaskFactory().StartNew(fun _ -> failwith "oops"                               
                                5)
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> Async.Ignore
|> Async.RunSynchronously

// POP!
```

What's the best way of treating regular (non-generic) Tasks as Async yet still get propagation of exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Xamarin F# Shirt App](https://github.com/xamarin/shirt-store-fsharp/blob/master/Shared/Helpers.fs) (which I originally borrowed from Dave Thomas):

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Async =
     let inline awaitPlainTask (task: Task) = 
        // rethrow exception from preceding task if it faulted
        let continuation (t : Task) = if t.IsFaulted then raise t.Exception
        task.ContinueWith continuation |> Async.AwaitTask
```

Comment: Just `let continuation (t : Task) = if t.IsFaulted then raise t.Exception` is probably clearer.

Comment: @Daniel Feel free to make it better.  :-)  I'm not possessive of my answers!

Comment: Think I first saw this here: http://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/f-helper-functions-to-convert-between-asyncunit-and-task/

Comment: downsides: cancellation is not handled properly, reraising exception drops the stacktrace

Answer (score 9):

As an option that will properly handle cancellation:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks

module Async =
    let AwaitTask (t: Task) = 
        Async.FromContinuations(fun (s, e, c) ->
            t.ContinueWith(fun t -> 
                if t.IsCompleted then s()
                elif t.IsFaulted then e(t.Exception)
                else c(System.OperationCanceledException())
                )
            |> ignore
        )
```

Comment: slight correction, the IsCompleted check must be made after the IsFaulted check because a fault is also considered completed.