# How to catch exception thrown by Task run with Async.AwaitTask

Tags: asynchronous, exception, f#, task-parallel-library

**Edit**: This turned out to be an F# bug which can be worked-around by using a custom option type instead of Fsharp's "Option".

In F#, I am trying to call a .net Task with Async.AwaitTask. The task is throwing an exception, and I can't seem to catch it with either try-catch or Async.Catch. And I know of no other way to catch exceptions. What is the solution? And what is the cause of the problem? Thanks for any explanation.

Here is some test code that shows my failure to catch the exception thrown by DownloadStringTaskAsync:

```
open System
open System.Net

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let test =
        async{
        let! exc = Async.Catch( async{
            try
                let w = new Net.WebClient();
                let! str = Async.AwaitTask (w.DownloadStringTaskAsync "") // throws ArgumentException
                return Some str
            with 
            | _ -> 
                return None // not caught
            }
            )
        match exc with
        | Choice1Of2 r -> return r
        | Choice2Of2 ext -> return None  // not caught
        }

    let res = Async.RunSynchronously(test)
    let str = Console.ReadLine();
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I need some way to catch the exception inside the "test" async function, preventing it to "bubble up".

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166363/async-await-not-catching-task-exception) related question, but I can't seem to adapt the answer (which deals with Task, not with Task<'a>) to my needs.

**Edit**: Here is a screenshot showing the problem: https://i.gyazo.com/883f546c00255b210e53cd095b876cb0.png

"ArgumentException was unhandled by user code."

(Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.1, Fsharp 3.1, Fsharp.core.dll 4.3.1.0.)

Could it be that the code is correct but some Fsharp or Visual Studio setting is preventing the exception from being caught?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but this code works perfectly fine for me (the exception gets caught in the try-with). Using F# 3.1.

Comment: It does not for me. See screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/4de542103442e020e20b46bd8d7541e4.png

Visual Studio 2013, .net framework 4.5.1, Fsharp 3.1, Fsharp.core.dll 4.3.1

Comment: @seguso, the fact that visual studio debugger breaks doesn't mean that exception is unhandled. Try running the application without debugger, does it crash? Can you also go to `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings` and see if `ArgumentException` is checked there?

Comment: @takemyoxigen:  I was misled by the fact that Visual Studio says "ArgumentException was unhandled by user code". See this other screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/883f546c00255b210e53cd095b876cb0.png

However, if I press continue, incredibly, the program terminates correctly. So you are right. However, in Visual Studio 2013 I don't have Debug > Windows > exception settings, so I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @seguso Sorry, my bad. In VS 2013 it's Debug > Exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The exception does get caught, it appears to be returning None out of async that's confusing here - the result is null, not None, which is screwing up pattern matching and generally being a bother. Use your own union type instead of Option to handle it.

**Edit:** Oh, and @takemyoxygen's comments about why you're seeing it straight away is correct. Debug->Exceptions, or just untick "Break when this exception type is user-unhandled" in the pop-up visible in your screenshot. It looks like VS is breaking on THROW, rather than actually on unhandled.

First, returning Some/None inside an Async.Catch makes it useless. Async.Catch returns `Choice1Of2(val)` unless there's an uncaught exception, so the code as is (if it worked) would return `Choice1Of2(Some(string))` with no exception, or `Choice1Of2(None)` with exception. Either use try/with and handle the exception yourself, or only use Async.Catch.

#### Experiments:

**Proof that we are catching:** Add a debug output to the "with". The code DOES get there (add a breakpoint or look at debug output for proof). We get `Choice1Of2(null)`, rather than `Choice1Of2(None)` in exc though. WEIRD. See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21sfH.png

```
open System
open System.Net

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let test =
        async{
        let! exc = Async.Catch( async{
            try
                let w = new Net.WebClient();
                let! str = Async.AwaitTask (w.DownloadStringTaskAsync "") // throws ArgumentException
                return Some str
            with 
            | _ -> 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "in with" // We get here.
                return None // not caught
            }
            )
        match exc with
        | Choice1Of2 r -> return r
        | Choice2Of2 ext -> return None  // not caught
        }

    let res = Async.RunSynchronously(test)
    let str = Console.ReadLine();
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**Remove Async.Catch:** Don't use Async.Catch (keep the debug output though). Again, we get to the debug output, so we're catching the exception, and as we're not wrapping in a Choice from Async.Catch, we get null instead of None. STILL WEIRD.

```
open System
open System.Net

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let test = async {
        try
            let w = new Net.WebClient();
            let! str = Async.AwaitTask (w.DownloadStringTaskAsync "") // throws ArgumentException
            return Some str
        with 
        | _ -> 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine "in with"
            return None }

    let res = Async.RunSynchronously(test)
    let str = Console.ReadLine();
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**Only use Async.Catch:** Don't use a try/with, just Async.Catch. This works a bit better. At the pattern match on exc, I have a Choice2Of2 containing the exception. However, when the None is returned out of the outermost async, it becomes null.

```
open System
open System.Net

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let test = async {
        let! exc = Async.Catch(async {
            let w = new Net.WebClient();
            let! str = Async.AwaitTask (w.DownloadStringTaskAsync "") // throws ArgumentException
            return str })
            
       match exc with      
       | Choice1Of2 v -> return Some v
       | Choice2Of2 ex -> return None  
       }

    let res = Async.RunSynchronously(test)
    let str = Console.ReadLine();
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**Don't use Option:** Interestingly, if you use a custom union type, it works perfectly:

```
open System
open System.Net

type UnionDemo =
    | StringValue of string
    | ExceptionValue of Exception

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let test = async {
        let! exc = Async.Catch(async {
            let w = new Net.WebClient();
            let! str = Async.AwaitTask (w.DownloadStringTaskAsync "") // throws ArgumentException
            return str })
            
       match exc with      
       | Choice1Of2 v -> return StringValue v
       | Choice2Of2 ex -> return ExceptionValue ex 
       }

    let res = Async.RunSynchronously(test)
    let str = Console.ReadLine();
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Using a try/with and no Async.Catch also works with a new Union:

```
open System
open System.Net

type UnionDemo =
    | StringValue of string
    | ExceptionValue of Exception

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let test = async {
        try
            let w = new Net.WebClient();
            let! str = Async.AwaitTask (w.DownloadStringTaskAsync "") // throws ArgumentException
            return StringValue str
        with
        | ex -> return ExceptionValue ex }

    let res = Async.RunSynchronously(test)
    let str = Console.ReadLine();
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

It works even if the union is defined as the following:

```
type UnionDemo =
    | StringValue of string
    | ExceptionValue
```

The following gets null in moreTestRes.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let moreTest = async {
        return None
    }

    let moreTestRes = Async.RunSynchronously moreTest
    0
```

Why this is the case I don't know (still happens in F# 4.0), but the exception is definitely being caught, but None->null is screwing it up.

Comment: So to summarize, 

1) this is a bug in f#, not in my code. the problem is that res = null instead of None.

2) If instead of option I use a custom union, the problem is gone. Res = MyCustomNone, not null. 

3) however, even if I use a custom union instead of None, the problem that the debugger breaks, and INCORRECTLY says "unhandled exception", still remains: https://i.gyazo.com/a79583a859f7eac8d83085e8c50f5ecf.png

Correct?

Comment: Well, technically the answer to your question is that an exception IS caught. You're seeing the exception because you always break on that exception. Uncheck the checkbox visible in your image, click OK/continue and then try running the code again – you shouldn't get the exception thrown in vs, just it getting caught in the with.

The rest of my answer covered why the pattern match on exc didn’t work, etc. - which appears to be caused by an F# bug.

Comment: you say: "you always break on that exception". 

Excuse me but it does not seem to me to be so. The checkbox says "break when this exception type is user-unhandled". It does not say "break always". I am handling the exception with try-catch, so it seems to me the dialog should not appear.

Comment: I don't have VS2013 installed on any devices any more, but I seem to remember that "user-unhandled" was related to Just My Code in some way. If you open the window (Debug->Exceptions) it should look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWapa.png

Comment: If you click "Reset All", is Argument Exception ticked for User Unhandled? Also, what happens if you go to Tools->Options, Debugging->General and untick "Just My Code"? Does VS still complain as soon as the exception is thrown?

Comment: Debug -> Exceptions looks like this: https://gyazo.com/6f15cfea42002451c7f6902842ea136e  

If I disable "just my code", Vs does not complain anymore as soon as the exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeah, disabling "Just My Code" hides "User-unhandled". The thing is, the call-stack is something like this: async -> Async.AwaitTask -> DownloadStringTaskAsync

Comment: DownloadStringTaskAsync is something you're calling, it's throwing an exception, and the exception is going into Async.AwaitTask (which is not your code). This means your exception was sent to non-user code - so you have a break on user-unhandled, because you didn't handle the exception before it got to non-user code. Disabling Just My Code means that it will let the exception bubble through framework code, and will only break if it's truly unhandled.

Comment: 8 years later, and this still seems to be an issue in F#, even with task keyword based parallelism instead of async